# How to show a UINavigationController on top of a UITextView?

Tags: iphone

I want to show `UINavigationController` on top of a `UITextView`. However it is not showing the navigation controller. Only the `UITextView` is visible.

This is how I am trying to show it:

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 10);

[myButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myButton];

[[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:button animated:YES];

[button release];

self.title = @"Info";

self.textView = [[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 416)]autorelease];

self.textView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

self.textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia-BoldItalic" size:14];

self.textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];

self.textView.layer.borderWidth = 1;

self.textView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];

self.textView.layer.cornerRadius = 1;

self.textView.textAlignment =  UITextAlignmentCenter;

self.textView.text = @"\nThis is UITextView\nThis is UITextView\nThis is UITextView\nThis is UITextView";

self.textView.editable = NO;

[self.view addSubview: self.textView]; 

 //[self.view addSubview:navigationController.view];

}
```

Any ideas what I am missing? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show a UINavigationController on top of a UITextView? That doesn't make too much sense. Why are you trying to do that?

You can show the UINavigationController over the current UIViewController by doing this:

```
[self presentModalViewController:navigationController];
```